# How do I display the text from a txt or doc document in a webpage without using iframe

Tags: html, iframe

How do I display the text from a txt or doc document in a webpage without using iframe
I used to use iframe but since the advent of xframe blocking by IE it no longer works with all browsers.
My aim is to set up a website and update documents or tables by updating individual files using FTP (Filezilla or such).
In this fashion the html pages themselves don't need to be accessed.

Comment: What language do you use.

Comment: Paste your current code.

Comment: If you use php then read it: http://www.tizag.com/phpT/fileread.php

Answer (score 0):

If you can use PHP, a solution would be to use

```
echo file_get_contents($fileName);
```

This way, whatever file is specified by `$fileName` would be displayed on the page.

Comment: How to sure he use PHP

Comment: I'm way out of my depth here, I'm using wysiwyg to create the website.
I'm ok with html and know a little java.
I've been happy until now just pointing the iframe at a file stored within the website on the server, and then if the document is overwritten using Filezilla, then there is no need to modify the website HTML documents.

Answer (score 0):

There is an API, which allows you to display file content. Have a look [here](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/reading-files-using-the-html5-filereader-api)

See, if it helps